# SonarAnalyzer.CSharp rule S2931 violation disappears from error list when source file is opened in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sonarqube, sonarlint

The SonarQube SonarAnalyzer.CSharp Rule S2931 is correctly shown in the ErrorList window directly after building the solution but disappears from the list as soon as I open the file containing the issue. This behaviour is pretty confusing and you loose the option to suppress the issue via the error list window. Is there a way around that problem?

Interestingly, the issue is still shown in the code editor and other rules seem to work just fine.

Here is an example to reproduce the problem (the code is from the rule documentation):

```
public class ResourceHolder // Noncompliant; doesn't implement IDisposable
{
    private FileStream fs; // This member is never Dispose'd
    public void OpenResource(string path)
    {
        this.fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    }

    public void CloseResource()
    {
        int i = 0;
        i =+ 1;

        this.fs.Close();
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015, SonarAnalyzer.CSharp  1.22.0.1631 & SonarLint 2.10.0.1098